# Is there any alternative for Source Mate tool in Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashdevelop

So I recently discovered this Source Mate tool for Flash builder with all the cool stuff like code fixes, hinting, code completing etc., but I was wondering if there is any free alternative for [this](http://www.elementriver.com/sourcemate) tool? Cause I don't think that paying for such tool is worth it when we need to pay a huge money for the Flash Builder Eclipse copy itself..
Should I just go with Flash Develop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not forced to buy Flash Builder, Adobe is decent enough to give the Flex SDK away for free, so you can use FlashDevelop or [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/home/) (latter not being that cheap either though, but comparable to SourceMate with the difference that it's a complete IDE).